# C++ stack class design

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++17

I am trying some hands on recent C++ standards. For the purpose of learning, I have implemented a Stack class as below which can hold any type of data member.

I would like everyone to review this class and give their suggestion on how any particular method should have been implement as to to adhere to SOLID principle's

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Stack
{
private:
#ifdef RAW
  std::any *_data;
#else
  unique_ptr<std::any[]> _data;
#endif
  int _size;
  int _capacity;
  bool validSize() const
  {
    if(_size>0 && _size<=_capacity)
      return true;
    return false;
  }

public:
  int getSize() const {return _size;}

  Stack(int _c=2):_capacity{_c},_size(0)
  {
#ifdef RAW
    _data = new std::any[_capacity];
#else
    _data = make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);
#endif
  }

  Stack(const Stack &rhs): _size(rhs._size),_capacity(rhs._capacity)
  {
#ifdef RAW
    _data = new std::any[_capacity];
#else
    _data = make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);
#endif
    //copy(rhs._data[0],rhs._data[_capacity-1],_data);
    for(int i=0; i < _capacity ; ++i)
      _data[i] = rhs._data[i];
  }

  Stack(Stack &&rhs)
  {
    _data = std::move(rhs._data);
    _size = rhs._size;
    _capacity = rhs._capacity;
  }

  void push(const any &data)
  {
      if(_size<_capacity)
        _data[_size++]=data;
      else
        throw "Out of memory &";
  }

  void push(any &&data)
  {
      if(_size<_capacity)
        _data[_size++]=data;
      else
        throw "Out of memory &&";
  }

#ifdef RAW
  Stack& operator=(const Stack &rhs)
  {
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
      _capacity = rhs._capacity;
      _size = rhs._size;
      for(int i=0; i < _capacity ; ++i)
        _data[i] = rhs._data[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }
#else
  void swap(Stack &rhs)
  {
    std::swap(_data,rhs._data);
    std::swap(_size,rhs._size);
    std::swap(_capacity,rhs._capacity);
  }
  Stack& operator=(Stack rhs)
  {
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
  }
#endif

  std::any top()
  {
    if(validSize())
      return _data[_size-1];
    throw string("Stack is empty");
  }

  void pop()
  {
    if(validSize())
      --_size;
  }

  ~Stack()
  {
#ifdef RAW
    delete []_data;
#endif
  }
};
```

I have tried 2 ways, one using raw pointer and other using unique_ptr. Tried to implement copy and swap idiom when unique_ptr is used.

There is a commented line in the copy ctor which was expected to copy the data but I couldn't get it right for the unique_ptr array. If someone can help to fix it.

Comment: Once you have all of the code working we would love to review the code, unfortunately this site requires that the code be working as intended before the review the code. There are other sites that will help you debug your code. Please read [Where can I get help?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @pacmaninbw Maybe you didn't get it right. Above code is working fine and I wanted to just get suggestion on how it can be improved further. Regarding the question on one of the fix, it is an add on which I though of asking and can be ignored. Review and suggestion was the main intent. Btw, didn't it compile/run when you tried ?

Comment: I only try to compile when I answer a question, my comment and down vote was based on this statement `There is a commented line in the copy ctor which was expected to copy the data but I couldn't get it right for the unique_ptr array. If someone can help to fix it.` I would suggest that you remove that from the question.

Comment: I don’t think it’s necessary to remove the comment and text. The question follows all CodeReview rules: the code works fine as-is (modulo some minor bugs, as usual), and the OP is merely pointing to an area of concern they want the reviewers to consider, which is fine. Beginners *frequently* make admissions like “I know this code is hackish and ugly, but I don’t know how to make it better”… seems cruel to punish one just for showing their *attempt* at making it better.

Comment: You're unlikely to get your wish for _everyone_ to review your code!  But you probably wouldn't want that anyway - it's better to get feedback from a few respected experts than to have to seek out the gems buried under the comments of the great unwashed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This design idea isn’t bad; a fixed-size heterogeneous stack could be useful. And this class’s interface is nice and minimal, yet completely useful.

Now, in *real* code, you would never see a class like this in use, for a couple of reasons:

1. In practice, an “any” type is… not really that useful. You never really have a use case where you have something that could be *literally anything*. There are many situations where you might have one of a small number of types… for that, there’s `std::variant`. But *literally anything*? Pretty much never.
2. Because you never really need *literally anything*, it would make more sense to make a stack restricted to a single type… just like the one in the standard library. (Well, the standard library stack is technically only an *adapter* that you wrap around a `deque` or `vector`, but, yanno.) A stack fixed to a single type will probably *hundreds* of times faster than a stack that holds *literally anything*—maybe even *thousands* of times faster—and much easier and safer to use (because you don’t need to futz around with converting to/from `any`, casting and such).
3. Even if you do need a small set of types, taking a single-type stack and using it with `variant` will be hundreds or thousands of times faster than using `any`, and easier and safer to use.
4. And in that ultra-rare case where you *do* actually need a stack of literally anything… you could just as easily take your single-type stack, and use `any` as the single type. It will be no less efficient than what you’re doing now.

So, in *real* code… you’d never make or use a class like this. But that doesn’t make it *bad*. If you were building a large program/library, this class would work as a quickie first pass, that you could later refactor and optimize. And if you really don’t care about efficiency *at all*, and you aren’t bothered about the clunky need to cast your types to/from `any`, then this class is just fine.

Okay, so this class isn’t going to be something you’ll find in a general-purpose library… but it’s still useful, so, let’s review it on its own terms.

Before we get into the actual code, let’s consider the interface. Whenever you are designing something that fits a standardized concept, you should make your interface fit that concept. In this case, you’re making a container, so your type should have [the standard container interface](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container). That means `size()` instead of `getSize()` (and it should return an unsigned type, which is not great, but, that’s the standard interface), and you need more functions, like `empty()`. You should also check out [the table at the end of the container library page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Member_function_table), to see what other functions are standard. In particular, you might want to look at [the interface for `std::stack`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack).

There are three very important reasons to copy standard interfaces:

1. The standard interfaces have been designed by the best C++ experts in the world. If they’ve done something a certain way, there’s probably a damn good reason for it.
2. If your type uses standard interfaces, it will be easier for other coders to understand it, and use it.
3. If your type uses standard interfaces, it can interact with… pretty much anything. For example, if your type uses the standard range interface, then it will automatically work with range-`for` loops. Even something as simple using `size()` instead of `getSize()` will determine whether your type works with `std::ranges::size()` and `std::sized_range`… which could make your type work much faster with some algorithms (or make it work *at all* with some algorithms).

One last thing: you should always use a namespace for your own stuff. The global scope is a dangerous place, with lots of unique restrictions that don’t exist anywhere else. Using a namespace saves you from a *lot* of headaches.

Okay, onto the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <any>
#include <memory>
```

There are two problems with this set of headers.

1. It’s incomplete. There are things your class uses that aren’t included. Most notably, `std::swap()` isn’t covered by any of those headers.
2. It has irrelevant includes. You don’t need `<iostream>` for your class.

```
using namespace std;
```

Never, ever do this.

I know some people will offer caveats like “oh, it’s okay to use at function scope” or even “it’s okay to use in a `.cpp` file, but not a header”. I don’t truck with those unnecessary exceptions. There is never a good reason to use `using namespace std;` *anywhere*, and it will *always* be risky when you do. There may be *less* risk doing it in a small function, but the risk will *never* be zero.

Just never do it.

```
  std::any *_data;
```

In C++, [we prefer to put the type modifier with the type](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout). In other words:

- `std::any *_data`: This is C style.
- `std::any* _data`: This is C++ style.

```
  bool validSize() const
  {
    if(_size>0 && _size<=_capacity)
      return true;
    return false;
  }
```

I have a problem with this function, and it is that it shouldn’t be necessary. The size should *never* not be valid. If the size is ever invalid… your class is broken.

Okay, but you’ve defined “valid size” to be non-zero, meaning an empty stack is an “invalid size”. Let’s put that aside for the moment and focus on the other part of the test: `_size <= _capacity`.

If the size is ever greater than the capacity, your class is broken. That should never, ever happen. So testing for it is specious. Why test for something that’s impossible? That’s just wasting cycles.

Okay, but maybe you’re paranoid, and you want to be 100% sure that the size never *accidentally* becomes larger than the capacity. Fine, but the place to do that test is any function where you modify either the capacity or the size. For example, at the end of `push()`, you could do `assert(_size >= 0);`, `assert(_size <= _capacity);`, and any other paranoid checks you want to do. Because they’re asserts, they’ll disappear in debug mode. But by making sure that your invariants hold at the *end* of every function, you can rest assured that at the *start* of every function, they’re good. That means for functions that don’t change anything, you don’t need to do any checks at all.

So the only test `validSize()` really needs is just `_size > 0`… which… is really just a test for whether the stack is empty.

And that makes perfect sense. Because that’s what you really need to check for in `top()` and `pop()`… not that the size is “valid” (which should *always* be true), but that the stack isn’t empty.

```
  int getSize() const {return _size;}
```

First, this should really be named `size()`, to match the standard container interface.

But you really should add some more markup here:

```
  constexpr int getSize() const noexcept {return _size;}
```

There is no way the function can fail, so marking it `noexcept` can not only add some performance benefits, it makes the function safe to use in no-fail situations.

And `constexpr` is really useful, when it can apply. As of C++20, `unique_ptr` is all `constexpr` (but `make_unique()` is not until C++23, sadly).

```
  Stack(int _c=2):_capacity{_c},_size(0)
  {
#ifdef RAW
    _data = new std::any[_capacity];
#else
    _data = make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);
#endif
  }
```

I’m not a fan of default parameters, and in this case, it really seems specious. Why 2?

If you don’t want the capacity to be changeable, then it might make more sense to not have a default constructor at all. Just have a constructor that takes a capacity. If you do really want a default constructor, then maybe make it possible to change the capacity (and in the default constructor, create a “zero-capacity” stack).

But there’s a bigger problem here, and that is that your stack is *implicitly convertible from integers*. That’s ridiculous; there’s no way that could be what you want. I mean, it would allow code like this:

```
Stack s = 2 + 2;
```

That’s just weird.

At the very least, you’ll want to declare the constructor that takes an `int` as `explicit`. You should almost always declare single-argument constructors as `explicit` (and almost never declare any other constructors `explicit`, but that’s something that some people will dispute).

But even an explicit constructor taking just an `int` isn’t a great idea. If you didn’t know this class, and say `auto s = Stack{2}`, what would you think that’s doing? Is it creating a stack with a capacity of 2? Or is it creating a stack with a *size* of 2, initialized with 2 default-constructed objects? Or is it creating a stack with a single item: the integer 2? The only way to know is to go look up the class’s documentation, and any time you force users to run to the docs, you’ve failed as an interface designer.

A better idea is to use tags. You could do:

```
struct with_capacity_t
{
    constexpr explicit with_capacity_t() noexcept = default;
};

inline constexpr auto with_capacity = with_capacity_t{};

class Stack
{
public:

    constexpr Stack(with_capacity_t, int cap)
        : _capacity{cap}
        , _size{0}
        , _data{new std::any[cap]}
    {}

    // ... [snip] ...
};

// usage:
auto s = Stack{with_capacity, 5};
```

Now there’s no mystery; it’s crystal clear what’s going on. You could even add other tags for other conditions.

```
  Stack(const Stack &rhs): _size(rhs._size),_capacity(rhs._capacity)
  {
#ifdef RAW
    _data = new std::any[_capacity];
#else
    _data = make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);
#endif
    //copy(rhs._data[0],rhs._data[_capacity-1],_data);
    for(int i=0; i < _capacity ; ++i)
      _data[i] = rhs._data[i];
  }
```

Okay, here’s where things are going to get complicated.

First let me answer your question: There are two reasons the commented code won’t work.

The first has to do with the fact that you are doing `_data[0]` and `_data[_capacity - 1]` as the input arguments. Firstly, for the latter, you probably mean `_data[_capacity]`, because when you are using an iterator pair, the second iterator is one-*past*-the-end. But that’s wrong here… and that’s the problem: Both of those are `std::any`s, because the brackets dereference the pointer. `x[n]` is `*(x + n)`. That’s not what you want; you just want `(x + n)`, no dereferencing. You could do `&(_data[0])` and `&(_data[_capacity])`, but that’s kinda silly (and wrong in the latter case). You really just want to do `_data` and `_data + capacity`. But that brings us to the second problem.

The second reason the commented code won’t work when using `unique_ptr` is because the last argument of `std::copy()` needs to be an output iterator. An output iterators needs two things, `operator*` (for dereferencing), and `operator++` (for incrementing). `unique_ptr` has the first… but not the second; you can’t do `++` on a `unique_ptr`. Of course, raw pointers support both derferencing and incrementing. The fix for the `unique_ptr` case is simply to get the raw pointer out of it, using `.get()`.

And, of course that’s also an issue for the first problem. `_data` works as an input iterator when it’s a raw pointer… not when it’s a `unique_ptr`. And `_data + _capacity` makes no sense with `unique_ptr`; you can’t do math with a `unique_ptr`. The solution here is the same: get the raw pointer out of the `unique_ptr` with `.get()`, and use that.

So:

```
  Stack(const Stack &rhs): _size(rhs._size),_capacity(rhs._capacity)
  {
#ifdef RAW
    _data = new std::any[_capacity];

    // Note I only copy up to size, not capacity. There’s no point
    // copying the empty elements at the end.
    std::copy(rhs._data, rhs._data + rhs._size, _data);
#else
    _data = make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);
    std::copy(rhs._data.get(), rhs._data.get() + rhs._size, _data.get());
#endif
  }
```

*However*… while the above is okay with the `unique_ptr` version, the raw pointer version has a bug.

The issue is exceptions, and specifically, what happens if, while copying the contents of `rhs._data`, an exception is thrown. If an exception is thrown during the copy, that memory just allocated in the line above will leak.

In practice, the usual way to fix that is to use… `unique_ptr`. Something like this:

```
  Stack(Stack const& rhs)
    : _size{rhs._size}
    , _capacity{rhs._capacity}
  {
#ifdef RAW

    // Allocate the memory, and store it in a temporary unique_ptr.
    auto p = std::make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);

    // Copy everything from rhs. If anything throws here, no problem; the
    // temporary unique_ptr will be cleaned up.
    std::copy(rhs._data, rhs._data + rhs._size, p.get());

    // Everything was successfully copied, so now we release the unique_ptr,
    // and keep the pointer.
    _data = p.release();

#else

    _data = make_unique<std::any[]>(_capacity);
    std::copy(rhs._data.get(), rhs._data.get() + rhs._size, _data.get());

#endif
  }
```

Of course, if the point of `RAW` is to avoid `unique_ptr`s completely, then the above is a bit silly. What you’d need to do in that case is use `try`-`catch`:

```
  Stack(Stack const& rhs)
    : _size{rhs._size}
    , _capacity{rhs._capacity}
  {
#ifdef RAW

    // Allocate the memory. If this fails, it will throw, so no problem.
    _data = new std::any[_capacity];

    // Set up a try-catch block, so we can do emergency clean-up in the
    // catch if necessary.
    try
    {
        // Copy everything. If it succeeds, great! If it throws, we go to the
        // catch block.
        std::copy(rhs._data, rhs._data + rhs._size, _data);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // There was an error copying, so delete the allocated memory...
        delete[] _data;

        // ... and rethrow whatever error happened.
        throw;
    }

#else

    // ... [snip] ...

#endif
  }
```

But, frankly, if I see a `try`-`catch` block, that’s a code smell. And you can see why in this case: by using `unique_ptr`, everything because cleaner and safer.

```
  Stack(Stack &&rhs)
  {
    _data = std::move(rhs._data);
    _size = rhs._size;
    _capacity = rhs._capacity;
  }
```

It’s a *very* good idea to make all of your move ops `noexcept`, if possible. And with your stack class, it *is* possible. No-fail moves are *crucial* for correct code in some really gnarly situations (for example, you *need* no-fail moves to safely store your type in a vector), and really help with efficiency too.

You have another bug here, and, once again, it’s in the raw pointer version. The `unique_ptr` version is fine. (See a pattern?)

The issue is what `std::move()` does. For a `unique_ptr` it (presumably) does exactly what you think it does. It ***TAKES*** the pointer out of the source `unique_ptr`, leaving it empty, and puts that pointer in the target `unique_ptr` (which, if it *wasn’t* empty, gets reset first, but in this case, you know the target is empty). In fact, because `unique_ptr` behaves exactly the way you think it should when moving, you could even default this entire operation:

```
  // works for unique_ptr version only
  constexpr Stack(Stack&&) noexcept = default;
```

With raw pointers, though, a move is just a copy. In general, a move is just an optimized copy.* If the copy is already as optimal as possible… then a move is a copy. That’s true for all the built-in types… including pointers.

- (Well, I mean, it’s more than *just* an optimized copy but… that’s getting too sophisticated for the discussion here.)

In other words, `_data = std::move(rhs._data);` is no different from `_data = rhs._data;`… which leaves `rhs._data` with its original value. When `rhs` gets destroyed, the memory gets freed… and then, later, when `this` gets destroyed, boom, double delete. Crash.

The fix is really easy, though. Just manually set the old pointer to null:

```
  Stack(Stack&& rhs) noexcept
  {
    _data = std::move(rhs._data);
    rhs._data = nullptr;    // this line is unnecessary for unique_ptr... but
                            // doesn't hurt (other than wasting cycles)

    _size = rhs._size;
    _capacity = rhs._capacity;
  }
```

As an aside, when I’m making a type, I usually don’t treat the move ops as fundamental ops. Instead, I usually treat *swap* as the fundamental operation, and define move ops—and sometimes the copy ops, too— in terms of `swap()`. If I were designing your stack class, I would do something like this:

```
class Stack
{
#ifdef RAW
    std::any* _data = nullptr;
#else
    unique_ptr<std::any[]> _data = {};
#endif

    int _size = 0;
    int _capacity = 0;

public:
    constexpr Stack(Stack&& rhs) noexcept
    {
        // Because of the data member initializers, when we get here, it's
        // basically an "empty stack". Size and capacity are zero, and data is
        // a null pointer (or empty unique_ptr, same thing).
        //
        // Which means that when we do this swap, we are putting a null
        // pointer into rhs, effectively leaving it empty. This is fine,
        // because the only things you can do with a moved-from object are
        // destroy it, or assign to it. (And we implement the assignment
        // ops safely for all cases below.)

        swap(*this, rhs);
    }

    constexpr auto operator=(Stack&& rhs) noexcept -> Stack&
    {
        // Basically the same logic as in the move constructor applies here,
        // except *this may not be empty. If it isn't, then when we do the
        // swap, we are putting *this's current pointer into rhs, where it
        // will presumably be deleted momentarily (when you are moving from
        // something, that usually means it's about to be destroyed or
        // assigned over).

        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    friend constexpr auto swap(Stack& a, Stack& b) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;

        swap(a._data, b._data);
        swap(a._size, b._size);
        swap(a._capacity, b._capacity);
    }

    // ... rest of the class

    // But I'll show the copy assignment operator as well:
    constexpr auto operator=(Stack const& rhs) -> Stack&
    {
        // This copy is dangerous, but if it fails and throws... no big deal.
        // We haven't even touched *this yet.
        auto temp = rhs;

        // Once we get here, all the dangerous work of copying is done.
        // Swapping is no-fail, so:
        swap(*this, temp);

        // That's the copy-and-swap idiom.

        return *this;
    }
};
```

In practice, that means the only things you really need to implement are:

1. A default constructor, if you want one.
2. The copy constructor. This is usually the most expensive and most difficult operation to get right. (Remember yours had a bug for raw pointers!)
3. The destructor, if necessary.

The move constructor, move assignment, and copy assignment are always the same boilerplate: just swapping or copy-and-swapping.

However, that’s all just the default boilerplate you should start with. In practice, it may be possible to do some of the operations much more efficiently. It is often possible to do the copy assignment much more efficiently; the copy-and-swap can be very wasteful. However… in *this* case… because you’re using `std::any`, you have to assume the worst-case, always (because you never know what’s inside an `std::any`).

```
  void push(const any &data)
  {
      if(_size<_capacity)
        _data[_size++]=data;
      else
        throw "Out of memory &";
  }
```

Throwing bare character pointers is unwise. You should use a standard exception class. In this case, probably `std::length_error`, or `std::out_of_range`. Or, if you prefer, you could make your own custom exception class, but you’ll probably want to derive it from `std::logic_error`.

```
  void push(any &&data)
  {
      if(_size<_capacity)
        _data[_size++]=data;
      else
        throw "Out of memory &&";
  }
```

Since you are taking an r-value reference, you should move the data, not copy it. That’s the point of this overload, right? To avoid copies.

Incidentally, you should also consider adding an `emplace()` function, to allow in-place construction.

```
#ifdef RAW
  Stack& operator=(const Stack &rhs)
  {
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
      _capacity = rhs._capacity;
      _size = rhs._size;
      for(int i=0; i < _capacity ; ++i)
        _data[i] = rhs._data[i];
    }
    return *this;
  }
```

Okay, once again, this is a raw pointer operation… and you have a bug.

You set the size and capacity of `*this`, which is fine… but you never do anything with the data pointer. What if the initial capacity is 3, and the capacity of `rhs` is 10. You’re going to try to copy 10 objects into a 3-element array. Not good.

To do this not just correctly, but *intelligently*, you need to consider a number of situations. For example, what if the current capacity is larger than `rhs._size`? In that case, it would be silly to reallocate; we have enough space!

But there is another thing to consider, too: what happens if any of the items in the data array throw during the copy. If you’re not careful—as in the code above—you may end up with the data half-copied. That’s a bad look.

Because you’re using `std::any`, there’s really no choice other than to always assume that copying might throw. (If you had used a templated type, then you could check whether that type might throw on copy. Then things can get more complicated, but also, much, much more efficient.) So your only real option is the copy-and-swap idiom:

```
#ifdef RAW
    auto operator=(Stack const& rhs) -> Stack&
    {
        if (this != &rhs)   // not necessary, but meh
        {
            auto p = std::make_unique<std::any[]>(rhs._capacity);

            // Note I only copy up to size, not capacity. There’s no point
            // copying the empty elements at the end.
            std::copy(rhs._data, rhs._data + rhs._size, p.get());

            // Dangerous part's done. Everything from here on out is no-fail.

            // It's safe to delete the old pointer now.
            delete[] _data;

            // And it's safe to get the new pointer out of the unique_ptr, and
            // save it.
            _data = p.release();

            // And of course, these are safe.
            _capacity = rhs._capacity;
            _size = rhs._size;
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
    auto operator=(Stack const& rhs) -> Stack&
    {
        if (this != &rhs)
        {
            // Copy...
            auto temp = rhs;

            // ... and swap.
            swap(*this, temp);
        }

        return *this;
    }
```

And since self-assignment is vanishingly rare, you can remove the `if` check, and just get:

```
    auto operator=(Stack const& rhs) -> Stack&
    {
        auto temp = rhs;
        swap(*this, temp);

        return *this;
    }
```

Which works for both raw pointers and `unique_ptr`.

```
  void swap(Stack &rhs)
  {
    std::swap(_data,rhs._data);
    std::swap(_size,rhs._size);
    std::swap(_capacity,rhs._capacity);
  }
```

This is not how you use `std::swap`. The correct way is to do [the `std::swap` two-step](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/07/11/the-std-swap-two-step/):

```
    void swap(Stack& rhs) noexcept  // noexcept is important for swap!
    {
        using std::swap;

        swap(_data,rhs._data);
        swap(_size,rhs._size);
        swap(_capacity,rhs._capacity);
    }
```

You should pretty much always do that when swapping. (I cheat in some of the code blocks above, because I know I don’t need the `using std::swap;`. But it really should still be there.)

As of C++20, you don’t need to do the `std::swap` two-step anymore if you do this:

```
    void swap(Stack& rhs) noexcept
    {
        std::ranges::swap(_data,rhs._data);
        std::ranges::swap(_size,rhs._size);
        std::ranges::swap(_capacity,rhs._capacity);
    }
```

In other words, use `std::ranges::swap()` rather than `std::swap()`.

```
  Stack& operator=(Stack rhs)
  {
    swap(rhs);
    return *this;
  }
```

This… is not a great idea.

The issue is that you really, really, *really* want the *move* assignment to be `noexcept`… but the *copy* assignment *can’t* be `noexcept`. So you *need* two functions; you can’t be clever and cheat and get away with one.

```
  std::any top()
  {
    if(validSize())
      return _data[_size-1];
    throw string("Stack is empty");
  }
```

First, this should probably be `const`.

Second, it seems a bit silly to *copy* the top element of the stack. Maybe the user doesn’t need their own copy of it; maybe they just want to peek at it to read it. Why not just return a reference to it? And if you’re going to do that, you should probably have both `const` and non-`const` versions.

Finally, as mentioned above, throwing a string is not a great idea. You should throw an actual exception object. In this case, `std::out_of_range` is probably the best choice:

```
    constexpr auto top() -> std::any&
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        return _data[_size - 1];
    }

    constexpr auto top() const -> std::any const&
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        return _data[_size - 1];
    }
```

If you *really* want to be stylish, you could also add rvalue versions, that intelligently return a copy, rather than a reference (which will probably dangle):

```
    constexpr auto top() & -> std::any&
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        return _data[_size - 1];
    }

    constexpr auto top() const& -> std::any const&
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        return _data[_size - 1];
    }

    constexpr auto top() && -> std::any
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        return std::move(_data[_size - 1]);
    }

    constexpr auto top() const&& -> std::any
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        return _data[_size - 1];
    }
```

It’s a bit repetitive, but that’s the best we can do until C++23.

```
  void pop()
  {
    if(validSize())
      --_size;
  }
```

There is a very subtle bug here. If you just decrement the size, you still leave the object in the array.

Consider this. Suppose I have a type that counts how many instances exist:

```
struct counting_type
{
    static int count = 0;

    counting_type() noexcept { ++count; }
    counting_type(counting_type const&) noexcept { ++count; }
    counting_type(counting_type&&) noexcept { ++count; }

    ~counting_type() { --count; }

    auto operator=(counting_type const&) noexcept -> counting_type& = default
    auto operator=(counting_type&&) noexcept -> counting_type& = default
}
```

Now I create a stack, put 3 of those in, and then pop them out:

```
std::cout << counting_type::count << '\n';  // prints 0

auto s = Stack{3};

stack.push(counting_type{});
stack.push(counting_type{});
stack.push(counting_type{});

std::cout << counting_type::count << '\n';  // prints 3

stack.pop();
stack.pop();
stack.pop();

std::cout << counting_type::count << '\n';  // prints ???
```

What do you think the last line should print.

I think just about anyone would guess that the last line prints 0. But… it doesn’t. It prints 3, because those 3 objects were just… left… sitting there in the stack after they were popped.

What you *should* do is not just decrement the size, but also clear the object being popped:

```
    void pop()
    {
        if (empty())
            throw std::out_of_range{"Stack is empty"};

        _data[--_size].reset();
    }
```

Now when you pop an object off the stack, it is actually destroyed.

Finally, there are some useful functions you’re missing. `empty()` would be *very* handy. `clear()` would be nice, too. It would be neat if the capacity weren’t fixed at construction time, and you could `reserve()`. `emplace()` would be useful, too.

You can see there’s really no benefit to using raw pointers. When you do, you still end up having to use `unique_ptr`s anyway, for proper exception safety. I suppose you could use `try`-`catch` blocks if you really *must*… but `unique_ptr`s will be simpler, clearer, and probably more efficient. `unique_ptr`s can be a *little* clunkier, because you can’t use them *directly* in most algorithms as iterators; you need to get the raw pointers out of them for that. But I think all-in-all, `unique_ptr` is the only way to go, in practice.

Comment: Good review; one tiny criticism is that I do often see code that accepts _any type_ - as C++ templates.  Well-written code will add `requires` to constrain the template, and in any case, it won't be instantiable with some types, but the implicit promise is certainly there.

Comment: Oh, I think I see what you mean.  It's a stack that can contain a _mixture_ of arbitrary types; yes, I agree that doesn't really have a use case.

Comment: I am happy that atleast someone took time to review and give such a comprehensive review. Lot of points to learn here. TBH, I am aware that this is not a real use case, so please forgive me for that, but my primary purpose was to write some code and learn on the design part. I think, I got more that expected in this answer. I might take time to understand each section and come-back on doubts if any. Please keep up with such good work !! :)

Comment: Moderators pressure required me to move this question from SO to this forum which was ok in the sense that SO should usually be pointing to one question as oppose to some generic discussion. But I had in the mind that the traffic is very low here and nobody might actually review. I am myself coming back after 2 days this was answered..